# Why Spring Data makes excess queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

There is the following JPA method of a repository:

```
@Query("select new com.example.sweater.domain.dto.MessageDto(" +
        "   m, " +
        "   count(ml), " +
        "   sum(case when ml = :user then 1 else 0 end) > 0" +
        ") " +
        "from Message m left join m.likes ml " +
        "group by m")
Page<MessageDto> findAll(Pageable pageable, @Param("user") User user);
```

Problem: instead of a single query specified in the `@Query` annotation, queries to select each message separately are still flying to the database.

Question: why so occurs and how to fight against it?

The whole code can be viewed on [github](https://github.com/drucoder/sweater)

**UPD1:** Query log:

```
Hibernate: select message0_.id as col_0_0_, count(user2_.id) as col_1_0_, sum(case when user2_.id=? then 1 else 0 end)>0 as col_2_0_ from message message0_ left outer join message_likes likes1_ on message0_.id=likes1_.message_id left outer join usr user2_ on likes1_.user_id=user2_.id group by message0_.id order by message0_.id desc limit ?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_0_, message0_.user_id as user_id5_0_0_, message0_.filename as filename2_0_0_, message0_.tag as tag3_0_0_, message0_.text as text4_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_4_1_, user1_.activation_code as activati2_4_1_, user1_.active as active3_4_1_, user1_.email as email4_4_1_, user1_.password as password5_4_1_, user1_.username as username6_4_1_, roles2_.user_id as user_id1_2_2_, roles2_.roles as roles2_2_2_ from message message0_ left outer join usr user1_ on message0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join user_role roles2_ on user1_.id=roles2_.user_id where message0_.id=?
Hibernate: select count(message0_.id) as col_0_0_ from message message0_ left outer join message_likes likes1_ on message0_.id=likes1_.message_id left outer join usr user2_ on likes1_.user_id=user2_.id group by message0_.id
```

**UPD2:** Still noticed that when I try to pass in Message to(m,...), then instead of m is not passed the object of the message, as I need, and the id of the message. Maybe this hibernate goes to the database for each message?

Answer (score 0):

Use JOIN FETCH and remove all EAGERs.

It is classic example of  n + 1  JPA / JPQL problem.

Comment: I changed left join to left join fetch but now I get an error 'query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list'.